# The Coroutine pause code doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to both C# and Unity and recently I began writing a game, but the program isn't able to read recognize my Coroutine, so the code excecutes itself very fast.
Anyway here is the code:

```
void Update()
{
    x = Random.Range(-7.84f, 7.84f);
    y = Random.Range(-3.66f, 3.66f);
    z = 0;
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    StartCoroutine(timePause());  
}

IEnumerator timePause()
{

  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
  StartCoroutine(timePause());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `StartCoroutine` does **not** delay the method calling it!

What you rather want to do is wait within the Coroutine. In fact `Start` itself can be one. And there is also no need to call a coroutine recursively, you can just loop forever like

```
IEnumerator Start()
{ 
    while(true)
    {
        x = Random.Range(-7.84f, 7.84f);
        y = Random.Range(-3.66f, 3.66f);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}
```

which is basically the same as doing

```
private float timer;

void Update()
{ 
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer >= 1)
    {
        x = Random.Range(-7.84f, 7.84f);
        y = Random.Range(-3.66f, 3.66f);
        transform.position = new Vector3(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you could create the WaitForSeconds before the while loop and just use that and not recreate a new WaitForSeconds each time the loop is executed.

Comment: Using Time.realtimeSinceStartup would be more precise and reliable than Time.deltaTime.

Comment: @Mabakay well depends how you define `reliable` .. in this use case it can lead to a lot side effects ... like summing them up surely wouldn't make any sense ;) and it depends whether you want real time or not .. I wouldn't suggest it as a general solution ;) .. you can still simply use `WaitForsecondsRealtime` or `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` in the cases where it is explicitly needed

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to change the position of an element over time every one second? If so, don't do it using Update (which is called every frame) but run corutine from Start method and do the change from corutine level where you wait for specified time and call it again.

Theoretically you could in the Update method check how much time has passed...but corutine will be easier in such a simple case.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(timePause());  
}

IEnumerator timePause()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

    x = Random.Range(-7.84f, 7.84f);
    y = Random.Range(-3.66f, 3.66f);
    z = 0;
    transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);

    StartCoroutine(timePause());
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it finally works!